# Copying values from selected row to a specific cells in another worksheet - macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of items and a new sheet button like this: [image: LIKE THIS]

For each item you have to be able to create new worksheet when you click on that button. It copies a worksheet from a template, one worksheet for a single row. Now i want to be able to copy some of the info from a row i select to that new worksheet cells when i click on the button and maybe rename the worksheet as a value in one of the cells (ID). The values i need are ID and name, maybe few more.

```
Sub AddNameNewSheet2()
Dim CurrentSheetName As String

CurrentSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

'Add New Sheet
Dim i As Byte, sh As Worksheet
For i = 1 To 1
Sheets("Predlozak").Copy After:=Sheets("Predlozak")
Set sh = ActiveSheet

Next i

On Error Resume Next

'Get the new name
 ActiveSheet.Name = InputBox("Name for new worksheet?")

'Keep asking for name if name is invalid - Here i want to change worksheet name to a specific cell value from selected row.          
Do Until Err.Number = 0
    Err.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Name = InputBox("Try Again!" _
      & vbCrLf & "Invalid Name or Name Already Exists" _
      & vbCrLf & "Please name the New Sheet")
Loop
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Anyone has an idea how can i make this work?

Comment: Please provide you code as text instead of a picture.

Comment: your For loop currently is not needed as you can simply add the sheet without the loop.

Comment: How are you planning on selecting a row? Where are you selecting this row from?

Comment: When a specific item is selected in the first worksheet (screenshot) and then clicked on "new sheet' button it should:
1. Create new worksheet based on a template
2. Assign worksheet name based on cell value (ID - last column in main worksheet) from selected row
3. Copy some cell values from selected row (ID, name, form) to that newly created sheet

Comment: Is main worksheet same as first worksheet?

Comment: See here for ways to find last column https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm  You can use the row number of the selected row to specify where to search across from.

Comment: Yes it is the same, there is only one main sheet with items. I should be able to create corresponding sheets for a single item from that main sheet.

Comment: you could look at using ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell or Selection to handle the selected cell before pressing the button. You can these use Resize or Offset  on the ActiveCell to define an area (Range) to copy, put that into a variable and copy to other sheet.

Comment: Now i'm getting values from wrong worksheet (the template) instead of main one.

Comment: where is your main sheet defined?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with, I also thought checkboxes would be a good way to pick the line, it's quite simple:

```
Sub AddNameNewSheet2()
Dim x As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim IdCell As Range, NamCell As Range, FormCell As Range

Set wks = ActiveSheet
Set IdCell = wks.Range("A:A").Find("TRUE").Offset(0, 1)
Set FormCell = IdCell.End(xlToRight)
Set NamCell = IdCell.Offset(0, 1)

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(1), Type:= _
        "C:\Users\*yournamehere*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\*yourtemplatehere*.xltm"

    ActiveSheet.Name = NamCell
Dim wks2T As ListObject
Set wks2T = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

With wks2T
    .ListColumns(1).Range(2) = IdCell.Value
    .ListColumns(2).Range(2).Value = NamCell.Value
    .ListColumns(3).Range(2).Value = FormCell.Value
End With

End Sub
```

I made the template a table cause it is easier to specify exactly where to put stuff. And it is more manageable as more data is added in the future.

[Sheet1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOZ0d.png)

[Sheet2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1XDH.png)